# Convert recursive merge sort to iterative using stack

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, recursion, iteration

I have implemented the merge sort recursively, using linked list, but I am also interested to implement it iteratively using a stack.

This is my recursive implementation:

```
typedef int element_t;
typedef struct node_s* node_t;

struct node_s {
  element_t data;
  node_t next;
};

typedef struct list_s list_t;
struct list_s {
  node_t first;
  node_t last;
};

list_t* empty_list() {
  list_t* l = malloc(sizeof * l);
  if (!l) return l; 
  l->first = l->last = NULL;
  return l;
}

void list_push_back(element_t elm, list_t *l) {
  node_t cur = create_node(elm, l);
    if (!l->first) {
        l->first = cur;
    }
    else {
        l->last->next = cur;
    }
    l->last = cur;
}

void list_split(list_t *l, list_t *l1, list_t *l2) {
  if (l == NULL || l->next == NULL) {
    l1 = l1->last = NULL;
    if (l) l1 = l1->last = l; //l1->last->next = NULL; is already implied
    l2 = NULL = l2->last = NULL;
  } 
  else {
    node_t slow = l;
    node_t fast = l->next;
    node_t prev_fast2 = fast, prev_fast1 = fast;
    while (fast != NULL) {
      fast = fast->next;
      prev_fast1 = fast;
      if (fast != NULL) {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
        prev_fast2 = fast;
      }
    }
    l1 = l;
    l1->last = slow;
    l2 = slow->next;
    l2->last = prev_fast2; //assuming length is even
    if (!prev_fast2) //then length is odd
      l2->last = prev_fast1;
    l1->last->next = NULL;
    l2->last->next = NULL;
  }
}

void list_merge(list_t *l, list_t *l1, list_t *l2) {
  if (l1 == NULL) l = l2;  
  else if (l2 == NULL) l = l1;
  else {
    while (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL) {
      node_t left = l1->first, right = l2->first;
      if (left->data <= right->data) {
        list_push_back(left->data, l);
        l1->first = l1->first->next;
      }
      else {
        list_push_back(right->data, l);
        l2->first = l2->first->next;
      }
    }
    if (l1) {
      l->last->next = l1->first;
      l->last = l1->last;
    }
    if (l2) {
      l->last->next = l2->first;
      l->last = l2->last;
    }
  }
}

list_t* list_merge_sort(list_t *l) {
  if (l->first != NULL && l->first->next != NULL) {
    list_t *l1 = empty_list(), *l2 = empty_list();
    list_split(l, l1, l2);
    list_merge_sort(l1);
    list_merge_sort(l2);
    return list_merge(l1, l2);
  }
  return l;
}
```

and what follows is what I did with the iterative one... I am still not yet to run it, but is this the right idea of how to go about it? I tried to push only the head because the last gets handled separately and is not helpful to push it.

```
list_t* list_iter_merge_sort(list_t *l, int size) {
    stack* s = create_stack(size);
    push(s, l->first);
    while (!is_empty(s)) {
      first = pop(s);
      if (first != NULL && first->next != NULL) {
        list_t *l, *l1 = empty_list(), *l2 = empty_list();
        l->first = first;
        list_split(l, l1, l2);
        push(s, l1->first);
        push(s, l2->first);
        l = list_merge(l1, l2);
      }
      else 
        return l;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't analyzed it fully but why is `first` and `last` pointers-to-pointers (`node_s**`)? Where are the pointers that these pointers point at stored?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not hide pointer nature behind typedefs (`node_t`).  With rare exceptions, it confuses more than it helps, and should be considered a form of obfuscation.

Comment: Personally, I write very few `typedef`s, and I generally do not write typedefs for structure types.  Typedefs increase cognitive load and needlessly hide useful information (this is not "information hiding" in the same sense that OO enthusiasts praise as a feature).

Comment: This ... `l1 = l1->last = NULL` ... is invalid because `l1` and `l1->last` do not have the same (pointer) type, and there are no implicit conversions between pointer types other than some involving pointers to `void`.  If your compiler is not warning then turn up its warning level or get a better compiler.  There are similar issues in other places.  As a matter of style, I would recommend not chaining assignments at all.  That would solve that particular issue and some other, similar ones, and it would make your code clearer to boot.

Comment: You're right with that, I missed it

Comment: re your "recursive" part, I see `malloc()`, but I don't see any `free()`s. `create_node` is not shown, but it's likely allocates new storage; then `list_push_back()` creates new nodes for the value it pushes at the back,  but what happens to the node that previously held that value? is its memory freed? your code shouldn't create new nodes, it should just re-link the ones you've already got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need a stack to do an iterative merge sort. Start with the smallest list sizes for partitions, keep merging such partitions pairwise and then repeat with the double size, ...etc.

Here is an implementation where I omitted the `list` type and only used a `struct node` -- it saves quite some overhead with creating lists, and setting their `first` and `last` pointers during the whole process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* create_node_before(int data, struct node *next) {
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    if (!new) exit(1);
    new->data = data;
    new->next = next;
    return new;
}

struct node* create_node(int data) {
    return create_node_before(data, NULL);
}

struct node* array_to_list(int a[], int size) {
    struct node *first = NULL;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        first = create_node_before(a[i], first);
    }
    return first;
}

void print_list(struct node *first) {
    while (first) {
        printf("%d ", first->data);
        first = first->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
    
/////////////////////////////////////////////

struct node* cut_and_next(struct node *tail) {
    if (!tail) return tail;
    struct node *next = tail->next;
    tail->next = NULL;
    return next;
}

struct node* list_merge_sort(struct node *first) {
    if (!first || !first->next) {
        return first;
    }

    struct node *tail, *second, *third, *dummy = create_node_before(0, first);    
    
    for (int size = 1, mergeCount = 2; mergeCount > 1; size *= 2) {
        tail = dummy;
        first = dummy->next;
        mergeCount = 0;
        while (first) {
            // Get the next two partitions at `size` boundaries:
            second = first;
            third = first->next;
            for (int i = 1; second && i < size; i++) {
                second = second->next;
                if (third) third = third->next;
                if (third) third = third->next;
            }
            second = cut_and_next(second);
            third = cut_and_next(third);
            // merge
            mergeCount++;
            while (first || second) {
                if (first && (!second || first->data < second->data)) {
                    tail = tail->next = first;
                    first = first->next;
                } else {
                    tail = tail->next = second;
                    second = second->next;
                }
            }
            first = third;
        }
    }
    return dummy->next;
}

int main(void) { // Demo
    int size = 18;
    int a[] = {14, 5, 2, 11, 17, 8, 12, 15, 6, 7, 10, 0, 16, 3, 13, 1, 9, 4};
    struct node *first = array_to_list(a, size);
    printf("Input:\n");
    print_list(first);
    first = list_merge_sort(first);
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    print_list(first);
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want the iterative approach to use a top-down algorithm with stack, then maybe go for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* create_node_before(int data, struct node *next) {
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    if (!new) exit(1);
    new->data = data;
    new->next = next;
    return new;
}

struct node* create_node(int data) {
    return create_node_before(data, NULL);
}

struct node* array_to_list(int a[], int size) {
    struct node *first = NULL;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        first = create_node_before(a[i], first);
    }
    return first;
}

void print_list(struct node *first) {
    while (first) {
        printf("%d ", first->data);
        first = first->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
    
int is_sorted(struct node *first) {
    while (first && first->next) {
        if (first->data > first->next->data) return 0; // Not sorted
        first = first->next;
    }
    return 1; // sorted
}

////////////////// STACK //////////////////////////

struct stack_elem {
    struct node *elem;
    struct stack_elem *next;
};

void push_node(struct stack_elem **top, struct node *elem) {
    struct stack_elem *new = malloc(sizeof *elem);
    if (!new) exit(1);
    new->next = *top;
    new->elem = elem;
    *top = new;
}

struct node* pop_node(struct stack_elem **top) {
    if (!*top) return NULL;
    struct node *topnode = (*top)->elem;
    struct stack_elem *temp = *top;
    *top = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return topnode;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////

struct node* split_after(struct node *tail) {
    if (!tail) return tail;
    struct node *next = tail->next;
    tail->next = NULL;
    return next;
}

struct node* merge(struct node *first, struct node *second) {
    struct node *merged = first;
    if (first->data > second->data) {
        merged = second;
        second = second->next;
    } else {
        first = first->next;
    }
    struct node *tail = merged;
    while (first && second) {
        if (first->data < second->data) {
            tail = tail->next = first;
            first = first->next;
        } else {
            tail = tail->next = second;
            second = second->next;
        }
    }
    tail->next = first ? first : second;
    return merged;
}

struct node* middle(struct node *first) {
    // find middle with slow/fast traversal
    struct node *slow = first;
    struct node *fast = first->next;
    while (fast && fast->next) {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
    }
    return slow;
}

struct node* list_merge_sort_iter(struct node *first) {
    struct stack_elem *stack = NULL;
    while (1) {
        while (!is_sorted(first)) {
            // Split off second half and stack it
            push_node(&stack, split_after(middle(first)));
        }
        struct node *second = pop_node(&stack);
        while (second && is_sorted(second)) {
            first = merge(first, second);
            second = pop_node(&stack);
        }
        // All is sorted? -> exit
        if (!second) return first;
        push_node(&stack, first); // Save sorted list for later
        first = second; // Unsorted list
        // Split off second half and stack it
        push_node(&stack, split_after(middle(first)));
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int size = 18;
    int a[] = {14, 5, 2, 11, 17, 8, 12, 15, 6, 7, 10, 0, 16, 3, 13, 1, 9, 4};
    struct node *first = array_to_list(a, size);
    printf("Input:\n");
    print_list(first);
    first = list_merge_sort_iter(first);
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    print_list(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it with the stack.

Comment: Oh, but you realize that is just using extra memory with no gain, right?

Comment: I am just interested for the fun of the problem

Comment: @Kim, thanks for marking it as accepted. I have added a version of the code that uses a stack. Hope it is what you are looking for.